# IE displaying some widgets incorrectly in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt, gwt-rpc

I have a strange issue in my GWT app. My application is working fine and looking good in Google Chrome and Firefox. But in IE, I am facing some issues in visual display of widgets. The issues are:

- ListGrid is having some extra spaces (with dark black spaces) between each column and misalignments of entire grid.
- In ListGrid I have implemented a functionality to do some task when clicking a particular cell in it. That is working good in FF/Chrome but not in IE.
- Each column is misaligned in ListGrid. For example, the column corresponding to row header 3 is aligned to row header 2.

Please help me in solving these issues.

Comment: Are you applying any css or are you just using the default look ?

Comment: @DrDro: i guess i m using default look only. but i m not sure about t. because that app is initially developed by someone else now i hav started working in t. but pls tell me where to check whether it is using default files or any other files ??

Comment: Which version of GWT are you using? There are many places where one can "plug in" a CSS file/rules into a GWT app: in you host file (in plain ol' `<style>` tags), in the module XML file, as a CssResource, in UiBinder's template files... You are better off using Firebug and Inspecting ListGrid and checking if something is overrriding its default styles (defined in `standard.css`).

Comment: @Igor Klimer: Hi i am using smartGWT2.1 version.

Comment: Hi.. i have a new css file attached to my project.. ie. in Project.html i have a new CSS file named Project.css  associated to it which is configured for all widgets in gwt (button,grid....). how can i configure it back to standard style ??

Comment: GWT apps are just HTML + JS + CSS - like I said, use Firebug (or a similar tool) to find out which styles are overriding the default ones from `standard.css`.

Comment: @Igor Klimer: Hi i have deleted that css file and even i removed the tag that includes css file in Project.html. but even after that i am getting same problem in my application. what shall i do now ?

Comment: hi i have added some more issues in Listgrid in IE....

Comment: *Again* - use Firebug or a similar tool to find out what is causing these style changes - *something* has to be responsible for it. And you might try a hard refresh (Ctrl+F5 in most browsers) and/or clearing your cache - AFAIR, the GWT Development mode likes to cache resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually **upgrading the SmartGWT library to latest version** fixed these issue. As i tested these issues earlier using firebug and IE developer tools, it seems the problem with CSS handled for various widgets in SmartGWT. 
Thanks every1 for your help

Answer (score 2):

Did you set "user.agent" property in your *.gwt.xml file to include IE?